# Android: Constrain a TextView to the side of the page programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Intuitively, this should be very simple. Here is what I want to do:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

However, I want to do it programatically. Here is what I have been messing with, but I am getting all sorts of errors.

```
val messageText = TextView(applicationContext)
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
constraintSet.connect(messageText.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, parent.taskId, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0)
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ConstrainSet.PARENT_ID` as the `endID` parameter:

```
constraintSet.connect(messageText.id, ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 0);
```

Should work.

Comment: Thank you it is compiling, so it's very close, but nothing is changing in my layout. What else could be the issue?